# How can I update multiple drupal 7 sites on my server, using drush

Tags: 7, drush

I just installed drush in my ssh home directory. Is there a drush command for updating all sites inside home directory that have drupal 7?

There is to mention that i have also non drupal sites and i would not like drush to mess with these.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a Bash script, and feed in all the folder names in the sites/dir into Drush.

See [this script](http://thejaffes.org/2013-01-20/bash-script-updating-drupal-core) for updating a Drupal site; modify it according your needs-

Remember that testing is a very important part of every site upgrade. You should include a manual testing phase after the pm-update, and then push each tested site back to the live site as they are found to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another script for updating multiple Drupal sites:

https://github.com/greg-1-anderson/utiliscripts/blob/master/drupal-backup-all

Make an alias for each site to be backed up.  This script will first make a remote copy, then it will copy the site again and update it.  You'll end up with two sites for each one you start with - a backup, and an update site ready for testing.  Push the code from the update site back to the live site after testing.

Answer (score 0):

Not long ago I had the same issue with a client server where he had a couple of Drupal sites and I found my self repeating the same commands over and over for each site. I wrote and small PHP code and I added a shortcut to my shell, now I just run "msu-drush" and all sites get updated even the unwanted text files like LICENSE.txt and COPYRIGHT.txt get removed. It worked for me so there is a big change it can work for you too.

See the PHP code in Drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/1926484